# Modifying variables of a Java Applet

Tags: java, mysql, security, applet

I am interested in working on a multiplayer game in Java. I am concerned about hackers modifying game data and right now I'm interested in running my game in an Applet and connecting to my MySQL database from there. I came from working with C# and XNA so I'm not extremely familiar with Java yet so I was wondering how safe an Applet is. Could someone somehow modify game variables of the Applet running in the browser? Could they somehow access my database?

Comment: Probably no. Difficult to access the server database or applet variables.

Comment: I'd be more concerned about traffic between the applet and server and/or DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, technically yes, of course they can: as soon as applet is downloaded, it can be saved, unpacked, decompiled, and changed.

Practically, I doubt anyone would care. If you care, though, the proper approach would be to  write your server in such a way that every request from client would be validated before acting on it.

As of connection to MySQL, there are two problems:

1. You are going to pass MySQL credentials to applet. How will you make it safe enough so that users wouldn't get directly in the database?
2. Many firewalls won't let you get through to MySQL ports. It's solvable, but do you have the solution ready? In most cases this problem is easier to avoid than solve.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am reading more about how it is done what I could possibly do in my circumstances. As you mentioned, for what I would like to try and do I doubt many if any would care to even try. Nonetheless still worth reading a little bit more about to gain a better understanding.

Comment: +1 Good answer.  *"You are going to pass MySQL credentials to applet."* Access to the DB should be mediated by server side code (e.g. servlet, ASP, PHP etc.).  Otherwise, expect the DB to become trashed.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance as I'm taking a class on PHP and MySQL so my knowledge is still limited anyway to topics such as security. I have WAMP set up and from Java I am using: "conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName,userName,password);" and "rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT ...");" So what I'd have people do is sign up for an account thru a website and that would give their account limited accessibility to the database. Of course this would mean the ability to modify values pertaining to their account. Where I don't understand is this idea of credentials. Could someone explain further?

Comment: Credentials is whatever you use to get access. Usually username and password, but can be anything, e.g., retina image. The approach you describe is a nice one iff executed properly. The main problem with this approach is, it's very hard to limit access: as far as I'm aware, there's no record-level access settings, at least not in mySQL. So if user can edit his details in the DB, he'll also be able  to edit details of *any other* user, and I doubt you'd like that.

Comment: I would not want to to happen at all. I do not want the user to have any access beyond their own settings, not the entire table giving them access to other user data as well. I will do some research and tests before I go any further. Thanks again.